# Connecto to mysql server

Tags: python, mysql, flask

i have a flask python web site, im trying to connecto to mysql server but get

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied
> for user 'root'@'xxx.xxx.251.67' (using password: YES)

i can reach the database thru mysql workbench using the data that im using in flask.

Iv tryed to flush previlegues
update root password
iv granted all permission on server to user root on %

but still get this error.

Anyone can help?

my code is

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="mysql.server.com",
  user="root",
  password="passs123",
  database="mydb"
)
```

[select user,host from mysql.user ;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7cRD.png)

[show grants for root@%;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6QL0.png)

Comment: What result `select user,host from mysql.user ; ` gives ? Does the user exists ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha hi, it return all my users and host

Comment: added img above

Comment: Have you checked the password, is it correct ?

Comment: yes the password is correct, iv checked

Comment: What gives `show grants for root@%` ?

Comment: please see above

Answer (score 0):

show grant for root;

check the privileges for root@'%' on mydb;

Comment: you can see the printscreen above

Comment: @bizric grant all privileges on *.* to root@'%';

Comment: iv done that, iv went to the server and grant all privileges on user root in %, iv updated the image above to have more info

Comment: how? you want me to create a user with all previleges to you?